# How to make the tableview display an item in an array with each button press in Swift 4.0?

Tags: swift

I'd like the tableview to insert a new row with a text that corresponds to a specific button i've pressed, but I'm not certain how to specify that in my code / UI.

Basically, i'd like the text "button #1 pressed" to appear when I press button #1, "button #2 pressed" to appear when I press button #2, etc. How can I configure that?

TableViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var myArray = ["button #1 pressed", "button #2 pressed", "button #3 pressed"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad(
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.FruitVegArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

}
```

SubViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class SubViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let tableVC = segue.destination as! TableViewController

}

@IBAction func button1action(_ sender: Any) {
}

@IBAction func button2action(_ sender: Any) {
}


}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47257112/6080920 check this if it helps you

Comment: Consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33234180/uitableview-example-for-swift. Also, searching the web for 'UITableView examples' is a good place to start.

Comment: Can you show us your storyboard setup so we can help you out

Answer (score 1):

Initialize myArray as blank

```
 var myArray = [String]()
```

and return number of rows count form myArray.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection 
section: Int) -> Int {
    return myArray.count
}
```

And now when button1 pressed then simply add "button #1 pressed" text in the array and refresh table view. You need to access myArray from your "SubViewController" class then add the text.

```
myArray.append("button #1 pressed")
 tableView.beginUpdates()
 tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: myArray.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
 tableView.endUpdates()
```

Same for button 2 or others.